# Logcat not working on my LG G4 (H815)

Tags: adb, logging, lg-g4

I can't read the logcat from my phone. As an Android Developer, this is terrible for me. The message that I'm getting is:

```
logcat read failure
```

Looking the sources, it seems like a generic error:

Code from [the source](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/logcat/logcat.cpp#L1263) (Github, logcat.cpp)

```
while (!g_maxCount || (g_printCount < g_maxCount)) {
    struct log_msg log_msg;
    log_device_t* d;
    int ret = android_logger_list_read(logger_list, &log_msg);

    if (ret == 0) {
        logcat_panic(false, "read: unexpected EOF!\n");
    }

    if (ret < 0) {
        if (ret == -EAGAIN) {
            break;
        }

        if (ret == -EIO) {
            logcat_panic(false, "read: unexpected EOF!\n");
        }
        if (ret == -EINVAL) {
            logcat_panic(false, "read: unexpected length.\n");
        }
        logcat_panic(false, "logcat read failure");
    }
```

My phone is rooted and has the bootloader unlocked. I'm using stock kernel. I've no clues. Any ideas, something to try?

Thanks in advance

Comment: **Flaggers:** Despite containing code, this is not a development question -- logcat is a command-line utility that is useful to all power users.

Comment: It's too bad that the return value is just dropped completely if it's not one of those three, it ought to be printed.  In any case, when did this start happening?  Does it persist after a reboot?

Comment: Thanks @Matthew. It started when I rooted it, and yes, it persists after a reboot (have been one month without logcat).

Comment: Hmm, could be some filesystem permissions that were messed up by the rooting.  SuperSU or a recovery like CWM or TWRP should have a "Fix permissions" option that you could try, although sometimes it makes things worse.

Comment: I'll try it, thanks. Hope not to make things worse ;)

Comment: didn't work... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a custom rom ?
I have the same problem, here is how I solved it partially:
Download this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Mx2p0Jd24Jcm9fNEV6d0xDV1E/view

Put this file to root/system/bin an rename it to logd. Attribut -rwxr-xr-x (755) an reboot your Phone. After that logging works.
This file has been deleted because it consumes a lot of battery.
After logging, rename the file in logd.xxx and restart your phone. Thereafter, the battery consumption is reduced again.

More Description
http://forum.xda-developers.com/g4/help/guide-disable-logd-process-battery-drain-t3308921#post65168793

then download a logcat reader app from playstore.
Unfortunately, logcat from computer still don't work :( I'm still searching a solution for logcat from computer

Comment: even from computer ? Personally I can't get it working on my computer

Comment: no, not from the computer... only with the **alogcat** app

Comment: :( tell me  if one day you get it working from computer....
If you are interested, I have asked the question in this xda thread:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/g4/development/h815-genisys-rom-1-0-classic-v10g-t3192649/page379
no response so far :/

Comment: OK, i'll tell you. Mine is not working, but have you tried to access a shell (adb shell) and execute the 'logcat' command?

Comment: yes, from window and ubuntu computer, I type ' adb logcat', and it says 'logcat read failure' :(

Comment: if I try just 'logcat' from a terminal emulator app, inside android, it says nothing.... this is strange

Comment: @n0tis @webo80 This is an old question, I know, but I recently encountered this same problem. The fix? After `logd` is copied to `/system/bin`, run `chcon u:object_r:logd_exec:s0 /system/bin/logd`. That should load it with the correct SELinux context.